# Unity Interface Missing

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

I currently have Gnome Shell, Unity, and Unity 2D (or Ubuntu and Ubuntu 2D, as they are now called) on Ubuntu 11.10. Gnome Shell and Unity 2D are working fine, but when log in with the standard Unity interface, I am completely missing the Launcher and Dash. My graphics card information is:

`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82915G/GV/910GL Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 04)`

The output of the command `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p` is:

`OpenGL vendor string:   Tungsten Graphics, Inc`

`OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) 915G x86/MMX/SSE2`

`OpenGL version string:  1.4 Mesa 7.11`

`Not software rendered:    yes`

`Not blacklisted:          yes`

`GLX fbconfig:             yes`

`GLX texture from pixmap:  yes`

`GL npot or rect textures: yes`

`GL vertex program:        yes`

`GL fragment program:      yes`

`GL vertex buffer object:  yes`

`GL framebuffer object:    yes`

`GL version is 1.4+:       yes`

`Unity 3D supported:       yes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is Unity plugin disabled in CCSM by any chance? When you login to Unity, just create a file on desktop and write ccsm in it. Save and close and do a right click on it, from permissions give this file exectable rights. After that just click it, CCSM will open. Try to activate Unity plugin there.

Comment: It turns out that the Unity plugin was disabled. I enabled it, and Unity works now. Thanks!

Comment: I am glad that you solved your problem.